# Input type 'text' not recognized by LastPass in extension both Edge & chrome

Tags: lastpass

I have some input types (text) & but the LastPass doesn't recognize the  `<input type="text">`.

But the input type text is not working
[image]

Sample code:

```
    <td class="ADTXTFFForm2" colspan="19">
<div class="" tabindex="-1"><input type="text" maxlength="255" name="V1$V2$V4$gbxMain$ffOTPCode$F" ft="VC" spellcheck="false" data-ms-editor="true" class="">
</div>
</td>
```

Could you please help us to LastPass recognize the input type text.

Thanks